# Finding the largest $3^k$ number less than the natural number

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

Given the natural number $N$ in binary representation (computer memory). How to obtain the representation of the $N\rightarrow\sum^{M}_{k=0}(a_k\cdot(3^k+1))$ form or, at least, how to find the $M$?

One solution is to take the $\left\lfloor\log_3(N-1)\right\rfloor$. But how to calculate (preferentially in $O(1)$ time) the $M$, remaining into the integer arithmetic filed (summation, subtraction, multiplication, division, remainder and comparison)? Is this possible in $O(1)$ time?

Comment: What are the $a_k$'s ?

Comment: $a_k$'s is just a coefficients. Natural numbers.

Comment: Do they show any particular structure or are they just random natural numbers ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The second variant.

Comment: Perhaps $\lfloor{\ln N\over\ln 3}\rfloor$?

Comment: Disregard my last. Perhaps $\lfloor{{\ln(N-1)}\over{\ln 3}}\rfloor$?

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Do you read the question completely?